# How do I print unique elements in Perl array?

Tags: perl, arrays, unique

I'm pushing elements into an array during a while statement. Each element is a teacher's name. There ends up being duplicate teacher names in the array when the loop finishes.  Sometimes they are not right next to each other in the array, sometimes they are.

How can I print only the unique values in that array after its finished getting values pushed into it?  Without having to parse the entire array each time I want to print an element.

Heres the code after everything has been pushed into the array:

```
$faculty_len = @faculty;
$i=0;
while ($i != $faculty_len)
{
        printf $fh '"'.$faculty[$i].'"';
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array but a hash.  I use arrays as little as possible.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with arrays, as long as they're used for what they're good at. :-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;
my @unique = uniq @faculty;
foreach ( @unique ) {
    print $_, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This works if installing MoreUtils is possible.  It's not always.

Comment: List::MoreUtils is a single module with no dependencies. You should be able to have a local copy of that module if you are on shared hosting

Answer (score 33):

Your best bet would be to use a (basically) built-in tool, like uniq ([as described by innaM)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439764/18097).

If you don't have the ability to use uniq and want to preserve order, you can use grep to simulate that.

```
my %seen;
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @faculty;
# printing, etc.
```

This first gives you a hash where each key is each entry.  Then, you iterate over each element, counting how many of them there are, and adding the first one.  (Updated with comments by brian d foy)

Comment: I think you really just mean this:

my %Seen;
@unique = grep { ! $Seen{$_}++ } @faculty;

Comment: This is the answer that works like uniq is expected to. I put it in a function: sub uniq {local %_; grep {!$_{$_}++} @_} thanks fellas :)

Comment: I would highly suggest using something other than `%_`. The `_` variable is used by Perl for magic things, `%_` may be one in the future.

Comment: This is my favourite answer - quick and does the job without requiring any additional packages. Nice!

Comment: A cleaned-up version of @ekerner's function wrapper, based on Robert P's suggestion: `sub uniq { my %seen; return grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @_ }`

Answer (score 14):

I suggest pushing it into a hash.
like this:

```
my %faculty_hash = ();
foreach my $facs (@faculty) {
  $faculty_hash{$facs} = 1;
}
my @faculty_unique = keys(%faculty_hash);
```

Comment: This can sometimes change the order of the elements.  Perhaps you could mention the possibility of putting "push @faculty_unique, $facs unless exists $faculty_hash{$facs}" inside the for-loop.

Comment: I figured for teacher's name, order wasn't critical.
If it is, it's probably alphabetical.  Still not too hard to solve.

Comment: You can always "sort keys %faculty_hash" to get a sorted (ASCII-betically) list.

Comment: instead of using a foreach, i'd use map:  my %faculty_hash = map { $_ => 1 } @faculty;

Answer (score 5):

```
@array1 = ("abc", "def", "abc", "def", "abc", "def", "abc", "def", "xyz");

@array1 = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @array1;

print "@array1\n";
```

Answer (score 5):

This question is answered with multiple solutions in perldoc. Just type at command line:

```
perldoc -q duplicate
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note: Some of the answers containing a hash will change the ordering of the array. Hashes dont have any kind of order, so getting the keys or values will make a list with an undefined ordering.

This doen't apply to `grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } @faculty`

Answer (score 3):

This is a one liner command to print unique lines in order it appears.

```
perl -ne '$seen{$_}++ || print $_' fileWithDuplicateValues
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found hackneyed 3 liner, enjoy

```
my %uniq; 
undef @uniq(@non_uniq_array); 
my @uniq_array = keys %uniq;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way to do it, useful *only if you don't care about order*:

```
my %hash;
@hash{@faculty}=1;
my @unique=keys %hash;
```

If you want to avoid declaring a new variable, you can use the somehow underdocumented global variable [%_](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11757)

```
@_{@faculty}=1;
my @unique=keys %_;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process the faculty list in any way, a map over the array converted to a hash for key coalescing and then sorting keys is another good way:

```
my @deduped = sort keys %{{ map { /.*/? ($_,1):() } @faculty }};
print join("\n", @deduped)."\n";
```

You process the list by changing the `/.*/` regex for selecting or parsing and capturing accordingly, and you can output one or more mutated, non-unique keys per pass by making `($_,1):()` arbitrarily complex.

If you need to modify the data in-flight with a substitution regex, say to remove dots from the names (`s/\.//g`), then a substitution according to the above pattern will mutate the original `@faculty` array due to `$_` aliasing. You can get around `$_` aliasing by making an anonymous copy of the `@faculty` array (see the so-called ["baby cart" operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby-cart)):

```
my @deduped = sort keys %{{ map {/.*/? do{s/\.//g; ($_,1)}:()} @{[ @faculty ]} }};
print join("\n", @deduped)."\n";
print "Unmolested array:\n".join("\n", @faculty)."\n";
```

In more recent versions of Perl, you can pass `keys` a hashref, and you can use the non-destructive substitution:

```
my @deduped = sort keys { map { /.*/? (s/\.//gr,1):() } @faculty };
```

Otherwise, the `grep` or `$seen[$_]++` solutions elsewhere may be preferable.