# How to merge two arrays without any duplicates

Tags: perl

```
@tools = ("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver", "boltcutter",
           "tape", "punch", "pliers"); 
@fretools =("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver" ,"blade");

push @tools,@fretools if grep @tools,@fretools
```

and i have get tools

```
  @tools=("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver", "boltcutter", 
       "tape", "punch", "pliers", "blade");
```

is there any easy way to do ?

Comment: So you want to merge two arrays without any duplicates?

Comment: YES .. Please ,I am not looking for some external module do this

Comment: my @employees1 = ("Fred Flintstone", "Barny Rubble", "Dino Fintstone");
my @employees2 = ("Wilma Flintson", "Bamm-Bamm", "Jigglypuff");
my @allemployees = (@employees1, @employees2); ( may be this  ) ?

Comment: Found here: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52/theres-more-than-one-way-to-do-it

Comment: @Kinopiko: it probably isn't helpful to post chat links just yet, since there's a minimum meta rep required during the "semi-private" beta.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print unique elements in Perl array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array)

Comment: @Tree: see blog.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @Ether: oh well, you only need twenty points. Go to meta.stackoverflow and write something about waffles or something, get the points, and join in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) CPAN module has a `uniq` function to do this.  If you do not want to rely on this module to be installed, you can simply copy the `uniq` function from the module's source code (since it is pure Perl) and paste it directly into your own code (with appropriate acknowledgements). In general, the advantage of using code from CPAN is that its behavior is documented and it is well-tested.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub uniq (@) {
    # From CPAN List::MoreUtils, version 0.22
    my %h;
    map { $h{$_}++ == 0 ? $_ : () } @_;
}

my @tools = ("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver", "boltcutter",
             "tape", "punch", "pliers"); 
my @fretools =("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver" ,"blade");
@tools = uniq(@tools, @fretools);
print Dumper(\@tools);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          'hammer',
          'chisel',
          'screwdriver',
          'boltcutter',
          'tape',
          'punch',
          'pliers',
          'blade'
        ];
```

Comment: +1 A variant that's even more compact: `map { $h{$_}++ ? () : $_ } @_`.

Answer (score 4):

There is sure to be a module which does this for you BUT without a module:

```
my %uniques;
@uniques{@tools} = @tools x (1);
@uniques{@fretools} = @fretools x (1);
@tools = sort keys %uniques;
```

This puts the tools in a different order. If you want to keep the order, you need a different method.

```
my %uniques;
@uniques{@tools} = @tools x (1);
for (@fretools) {
    push @tools, $_ if ! $uniques{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a hash, then extract the keys to get the unique elements:

```
use strict; 

my @tools = ("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver", "boltcutter", "tape", "punch", "pliers");  
my @fretools =("hammer", "chisel", "screwdriver" ,"blade"); 

push @tools,@fretools if grep @tools,@fretools;

my %hash   = map { $_, 1 } @tools;
my @array = keys %hash;

print "@array";
```