# How to push duplicate element of an array to a new array perl

Tags: perl

Can anybody tell me how to push a duplicate element of an array to a new array? 
This is what I have till now, again I want to retain the duplicate elements into a new array.

```
%seen = ();
@uniq = ();
foreach $item (@list) {
    unless ($seen{$item}) {
        $seen{$item} = 1;
        push(@uniq, $item);
    }
}
print "@unique\n";
```

Comment: Are you trying to find *duplicates*, as your text says, or are you trying to *remove* duplicates as your code says?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to find values that appear more than once:

```
my @seen;
my @dups = grep ++$seen{$_} == 2, @list;
```

```
@list = qw( foo bar baz foo foo moo bar );
  gives
@dups = qw( foo bar );
```

---

If you're trying to put the values that are only found once in `@uniq` and values that are found twice or more in `@dups`:

```
my %counts; 
++$counts{$_} for @list;

my (@uniq, @dups);
for (@list) {
   my $count = $counts{$_};
   push @uniq, $_ if $count == 1;
   push @dups, $_ if $count == 2;
}
```

```
@list = qw( foo bar baz foo foo moo bar );
  gives
@uniq = qw( baz moo );
@dups = qw( foo bar );
```

---

If you're trying to put the first instance of a value in `@uniq` and the second and subsequent values in `@dups`:

```
my (@uniq, @dups, %seen);
push @{ $seen{$_}++ ? \@dups : \@uniq }, $_ for @list;
```

```
@list = qw( foo bar baz foo foo moo bar );
  gives
@uniq = qw( foo bar baz moo );
@dups = qw( foo foo bar );
```

Answer (score 6):

Always start your scripts with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my @list = ( 1 .. 10 , 2 , 5 , 6 ) ;

my %seen = ();
foreach my $item (@list) {
  $seen{$item}++ ;
}

my @uniq = grep { $seen{$_} == 1 } keys %seen ;
my @not_unique = grep { $seen{$_} > 1 } keys %seen ;
```

Simply count each occurrence of the elements in a hash and use a grep afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish... do you want to remove duplicates, or find them?  Here's a solution for either:

### To remove duplicates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3);

my %unique;
@unique{ @list } = ();
print join(',',sort keys %unique)."\n";
```

Output:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6

### To grab only duplicates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3);

my %dupes;
%dupes = map { $_ => $dupes{$_}++ } @list;
delete @dupes{ grep { $dupes{$_} == 0 } keys %dupes };
print join(',',sort keys %dupes)."\n";
```

Output:

> 1,2,3

Comment: `sub uniq { my %seen; grep ! $seen{$_}++, @_ }` will maintain the order of the list, as will `sub dupe { my %seen; grep $seen{$_}++, @_ }`

Comment: @Zaid: A nice addition. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same logic as yours, but different statements.

```
use strict;
my @ar = (1,2,3,4,1,2);
my %ar = map { $_ ,  1 } @ar ;
my @ar1 = keys %ar;

print @ar1;
```

[Also check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array)

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating duplicates is this simple:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<uniq>;

my @uniq = uniq @list;
```

Getting duplicates, requires a little more explicit Perl:

```
my %seen;
my @dups = grep { ++$seen{ '' . $_ } == 2 } @list;
```

Answer (score 2):

You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your programs, and declare all variables using `my` at their point of first use. In this case it would have shown you that you were addaing data to the array `@uniq` but displaying the contents of `@unique`.

This program will print a list of all unique data items, and a second list of data that has occurred twice or more

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw/ a a a b b c /;

my %seen;
my @uniq;
my @multiple;

foreach my $item (@list) {
  if (not $seen{$item}++) {
    push @uniq, $item;
  }
  elsif ($seen{$item} == 2) {
    push @multiple, $item;
  }
}
print "Unique: @uniq\n";
print "Multiple: @multiple\n";
```