# Split functions

Tags: perl

I want to get the split characters. I tried the below coding, but I can able to get the splitted text only. However if the split characters are same then it should be returned as that single characters 
For example if the string is "asa,agas,asa" then only , should be returned.
So in the below case I should get as "| : ;" (joined with space)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "Welcome|a:g;v";
my @value = split /[,;:.%|]/, $str;

foreach my $final (@value) {
    print $final, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get the opposite of split

try:

```
my @value=split /[^,;:.%|]+/,$str;
```

It will split on anything **but** the delimiters you set.

Correction after commnets:

```
my @value=split /[^,;:.%|]+/,$str;
shift @value;
```

Comment: technically that will be wrong because there will be an empty item as  first item in array?

Comment: I believe it also gives the wrong answer if two of the punctuation characters are next to each other. (But the OP wasn't clear on what he wanted.)

Comment: @Myforwik Correct, but it will presumably be always the first element. I will edit the answer to reflect that

Comment: @ilomambo: Still wrong, as there will be no initial empty field if the string *starts* with a punctuation character.

Comment: @Borodin Hence the word "presumably". Anyway, the OP wants unique results, so I posted 6 hours ago another solution in a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

`split` splits a string into elements when given what *separates* those elements, so `split` is not what you want. Instead, use:

```
my @punctuations = $str =~ /([,;:.%|])/g;
```

Comment: @siva2012, this will get a list all of the delimiters, with repetitions.  In order to only get the unique delimiters out of that, look at this question about finding unique array elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array

Answer (score 0):

this works fine, and gives unique answers

```
@value = ();
foreach(split('',",;:.%|")) { push @value,$_ if $str=~/$_/; }
```

Comment: The same as `my @value = grep $str =~ /$_/, split //, ',;:.%|';`

Comment: Sorry - should be `my @value = grep $str =~ /\Q$_/, split //, ',;:.%|'`

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the separators only once, you need something more elaborate

```
my @punctuations = keys %{{ map { $_ => 1 } $str =~ /[,;:.%|]/g }};
```

Comment: @ilomambo: Yes, it does. What makes you say otherwise?

Comment: I ran it in perl and it gave only 3 out of 4 delimiters

Comment: Sorry, I ran it in perl, it is the other one that's wrong :::  \@value = grep $str =~ /$_/, split //, ',;:.%|' ::: It gave "." in \@value, and it is not in $str :::: Anyway, I think the OP has several choices now to solve his/her problem, an also a good hint that in perl there are 10 ways to do the same, good learning.

Comment: @ilomambo: Ah yes you're right - `/./` needs escaping. I'll add another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you call "split characters" what the rest of us call "delimiters" -- if so, the POSIX character class [`[:punct:]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes) might prove valuable.

OTOH, if you have a defined list of delimiters, and all you want to do is list the ones present in the string, it's much more efficient to use `m//` rather than `split`.