# To push unique elements read from file using regex into array-Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

Here is my file:

```
  heaven
  heavenly
  heavenns
  abc
  heavenns
  heavennly
```

According to my code, only `heavenns` and `heavennly` should be pushed into `@myarr`, and they should be in array only one time. How to do that?

```
my $regx = "heavenn\+";
my $tmp=$regx;

$tmp=~ s/[\\]//g;

$regx=$tmp;
print("\nNow regex:", $regx);

my $file  = "myfilename.txt";

my @myarr;
open my $fh, "<", $file;  
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
 if ($line =~ /$regx/){
    print $line;
push (@myarr,$line);
}
}

print ("\nMylist:", @myarr); #printing 2 times heavenns and heavennly
```

Comment: Why the rigmarole with the backslash before the plus, and then carefully removing it?

Comment: Note: `"heavenn\+"` and `"heavenn+"` produce the same string.

Comment: Note: `heavenn` and `heavenn+` are the same if you don't capture what is matched.

Comment: I don't buy that the use of `csh` has anything to do with the behaviour of your Perl script (unless you're doing something insane like creating the script as a string on the command line; then anything is possible given the metasyntactic zoo of operators in the `csh`).  Of course, there are those (including me) who'd argue that you shouldn't be using `csh` in the first place, but that's your funeral, not mine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - some people enjoy pain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Perl, so There's More Than One Way To Do It (TMTOWTDI).  Here's one of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = "heavenn+";
my $rx = qr/$regex/;
print "Regex: $regex\n";

my $file  = "myfilename.txt";
my %list;
my @myarr;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open $file: $?";

while ( my $line = <$fh> )
{
    if ($line =~ $rx)
    {
        print $line;
        $list{$line}++;
    }
}

push @myarr, sort keys %list;

print "Mylist: @myarr\n";
```

Sample output:

```
Regex: heavenn+
heavenns
heavenns
heavennly
Mylist: heavennly
 heavenns
```

The sort isn't necessary (but it presents the data in a sane order).  You could add items to the array when the count in `$list{$line}` is 0.  You could chomp the input lines to remove the newline.  Etc.

---

> What if I want to push only particular words. For example, if my file is, 1. "heavenns hello" 2. "heavenns hi", "3.heavennly good". What to do to print only 'heavenns' and 'heavennly'?

Then you have to arrange to capture the word only.  That means refining the regex.  Assuming you want `heavenn` at the start of the word and don't mind what alphabetic characters come after that, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = '\b(heavenn[A-Za-z]*)\b';  # Single quotes necessary!
my $rx = qr/$regex/;
print "Regex: $regex\n";

my $file  = "myfilename.txt";
my %list;
my @myarr;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Failed to open $file: $?";

while ( my $line = <$fh> )
{
    if ($line =~ $rx)
    {
        print $line;
        $list{$1}++;
    }
}

push @myarr, sort keys %list;

print "Mylist: @myarr\n";
```

Data file:

```
1. "heavenns hello"
2. "heavenns hi",
"3.heavennly good". What to d
heaven
heavenly
heavenns
abc
heavenns
heavennly
```

Output:

```
Regex: \b(heavenn[A-Za-z]*)\b
1. "heavenns hello"
2. "heavenns hi",
"3.heavennly good". What to d
heavenns
heavenns
heavennly
Mylist: heavennly heavenns
```

Note that the names in the list no longer include newlines.

---

#### After a chat

This version takes a regex from the command line.  The script invocation is:

```
perl script.pl -p 'regex' [file ...]
```

It will read from standard input if no file is specified on the command line (better than having a fixed input file name — by a large margin).  It looks for multiple occurrences of the specified regex on each line, where the regex can be preceded by or followed by (or both) 'word characters' as specified by `\w`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;
getopts('p:', \%opts) or die "Usage: $0 [-p 'regex']\n";

my $regex_base = 'heavenn';
#$regex_base = $ARGV[0] if defined $ARGV[0];
$regex_base = $opts{p} if defined $opts{p};

my $regex = '\b(\w*' . ${regex_base} . '\w*)\b';
my $rx = qr/$regex/;
print "Regex: $regex (compiled form: $rx)\n";

my %list;
my @myarr;

while (my $line = <>)
{
    while ($line =~ m/$rx/g)
    {
        print $line;
        $list{$1}++;
        #$line =~ s///;
    }
}

push @myarr, sort keys %list;

print "Matched words: @myarr\n";
```

Given the input file:

```
1. "heavenns hello"
2. "heavenns hi",
"3.heavennly good". What to d
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
An unheavenly host.  Good heavens! It heaves to like a yacht!
heaven
Is it heavens
heavenly
heavenns
abc
heavenns
heavennly
```

You can get outputs such as:

```
$ perl script.pl -p 'e\w*?ly' myfilename.txt
Regex: \b(\w*e\w*?ly\w*)\b (compiled form: (?^:\b(\w*e\w*?ly\w*)\b))
"3.heavennly good". What to d
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
An unheavenly host.  Good heavens! It heaves to like a yacht!
heavenly
heavennly
Matched words: equally heavenly heavennly heavennnly heavennnnly unheavenly
$ perl script.pl myfilename.txt
Regex: \b(\w*heavenn\w*)\b (compiled form: (?^:\b(\w*heavenn\w*)\b))
1. "heavenns hello"
2. "heavenns hi",
"3.heavennly good". What to d
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
Good heavennsy! What a heavennnly output from an equally heavennnnly input!
heavenns
heavenns
heavennly
Matched words: heavennly heavennnly heavennnnly heavenns heavennsy
$
```

Comment: Hey tanks.. But I've one more doubt now. What if I want to push only particular words. Exa, 1) If my file is, 1. "heavenns hello" 2. "heavenns hi", "3.heavennly good".. What to do to print only 'heavenns' and 'heavennly'??

Comment: Have you got blanks on the ends of your lines?

Comment: No. I don't have blanks.

Comment: You'd have to show me a hex dump of the file so I can see what's up.  There must be something different between the lines if 'duplicates' are appearing.  What that difference is, I don't know, but there must be one.

Comment: Hey I used the below mentioned answer. That chomp one.  Now it's printing unique values, but how to get only 'words'???

Comment: If you're using my second script, it only records unique 'words'.  Or do you have some other definition of 'word' in mind?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33879/discussion-between-karate-kid-and-jonathan-leffler)

Comment: Hi, What I want to do is, from the whole sentences, only words matching the pattern should be printed..
Like, from 'heavenns good' ,heavenns bad', 'heavennly good', 'bad heavennly bad', only heavenns and heavennly should be printed

Answer (score 1):

For a given value in `$_`, `!$seen{$_}++` is only true the first time it's executed.

```
my $regx = qr/heavenn/;

my @matches;
my %seen;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   push(@mymatches, $_) if /$regx/ && !$seen{$_}++;
}
```

Comment: if so, you've changed something. Can't help you if you don't tell us when you changed.

Comment: I put <fh> in my while as in my above code and using '$line' instead of '$_'

Comment: Thanks it worked.. Now can you tell me how do I only extract words?

Comment: `push @mymatches, grep !$seen{$_}++, /($regx)/g;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push only the first occurance of a word, you can add the following in your loop, after the regex:

```
# Assumes "my %seen;" is declared outside the loop.
next if $seen{$line}++;
```

More approaches to uniqueness: [How do I print unique elements in Perl array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array)

Comment: Where to put this next if?

Comment: @karate_kid - after `if ($line =~ /$regx/){`