# Why this piece of code will work for finding the unique element of the array in perl

Tags: perl

I have found this piece of code:

```
my %seen = ();
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @t_array;
```

(via:[How do I print unique elements in Perl array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array))

However, I do not understand why it would work. I know that `$_` refers to the element in the array. But why we need the `++` after it?

Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`$seen{$_}++` increments the value of `$seen{$_}`, and evaluates to the original value. So it evaluates to zero (false) the first time a given value is seen,<sup>1</sup> and to a positive value (true) every subsequent time. So `! $seen{$_}++` is true the first time the given value is seen, and false thereafter.

1. *Pedantic note: Technically, zero is not the original value. The original value is 'undefined'. But `++` converts undefined to zero before it begins work, and returns zero when it's done. But you'd actually get the same result either way, since undefined is false just as zero is.*

Comment: Is your pedantic note also known as autovivificaton?

Comment: @squiguy: no, just a useful anomaly of the postfix ++ operator.

Comment: @squiguy: No, not exactly. "Autovivification" is when you treat an undefined as a reference: the requisite anonymous object is instantly created. What `++` does is very similar, but the term is not used. (I think the main reason the term "autovivification" is so well-known is that it's sometimes a bad thing: if you write `if ($foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'})` when you mean `if ($foo->{'bar'} && $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'})`, you may never realize that you're accidentally mutating your data with what looks like a read-only expression. `++` is obviously mutating the data, so there's no gotcha.)

Answer (score 1):

```
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @t_array;
```

is equivalent to

```
my @unique = grep {

  # have we seen value of $_ yet?
  my $not_seen_yet = ! $seen{ $_ };
  # increment hash value by 1 for $_ key
  $seen{ $_ } += 1;
  $not_seen_yet;

} @t_array;
```

`++` is [autoincrement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) operator:

> if placed before a variable, they increment or decrement the variable by one before returning the value, and if placed after, increment or decrement after returning the value

Comment: They aren't completely equivalent, as `++` is magical. If you had `$seen{a} = 'a';` before the `grep` and one `a` in `@t_array`, then `$seen{a}` would be `1` instead of `'b'`. Although the contents of `@unique` would still be identical, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @BradGilbert yes, but hash starts empty `my %seen = ();` so hash values can be only numbers.