# Get unique string occurrence and display it

Tags: awk

I'm not really good with `awk`, so here what I just did to count the number occurence in one row:

the input.txt has this:

```
18 18 21 21 21 21 18 21
```

I just want to display the unique number that occur above. So, here is my code:

```
input="input.txt"

output=$(fmt -1 "$input" | sort | uniq | awk '{printf $1","}')

echo "$output"
```

The output:

```
18,21,
```

I got the result correctly but that comma `,` at the end, how do I remove that comma? Also, is there a simpler or a clean method without using `fmt` ?

The expected output:

```
18,21
```

Edit to remove comma, I use this:

`sed 's/,$//'`

and it's working, but is there a simpler way to do this without using `fmt` ?

Comment: Sorry I got it by using this: `sed 's/,$//'` but is there a simpler method of doing this without fmt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(!arr[$i]++){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  print val
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ OFS="," }               ##Setting output field separator as comma here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){          ##Traversing through all fields of currnet line here.
    if(!arr[$i]++){            ##Checking condition if arr is NOT having current field present in it
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i   ##Creating val and keep adding values to it, to print at last all values.
    }
  }
  print val                    ##printing val here.
  val=""                       ##Nullify val here.
}' Input_file                  ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: is there a way to put that comma if using this solution?

Comment: @Azimah, Done please check now and let me know?

Comment: Thank you this is working and this code is pure `awk` which is what I need. I only can accept this answer in 4 minutes (the site told). Also thank you so much for the comment effort.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way in `gnu awk`:

```
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]+' '!seen[$1]++{s=s (s!=""?",":"") $1} END{print s}' file.txt
```

```
18,21
```

Comment: nice solution, but doesn't exactly match OP's expected output format.. also, regexp RS is GNU awk specific I think

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of `perl` has `uniq` in standard library. Otherwise, you'll have to manually write the logic ([How do I print unique elements in Perl array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439647/how-do-i-print-unique-elements-in-perl-array)) or use https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils

```sh
perl -MList::Util=uniq -lane 'print join ",", uniq @F'

perl -lane 'print join ",", grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @F'
```

With `ruby`

```sh
ruby -ane 'puts $F.uniq * ","'
```

Comment: ++ awk is missing this built-in `join`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem today and I solved it by using echo,tr,sed. Code for your example is as below -

echo -n "18 18 21 21 21 21 18 21" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'

output- 18,21

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '18 18 21 21 21 21 18 21' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'END { print "\n" } !___[$_]-- && $!NF= NF < ++__\
>                          ? ","$_ : $_'  ORS= RS='[\t- ]+'
> ```

```
18,21
```

or if u don't mind chaining up 2 `awk`s :

> ```
> mawk '!__[$_]--' ORS=',' RS='[\t- ]+' | mawk 7 RS=',$'
> ```

```
18,21
```